# How can I do a changeset based merge instead of file-by-file based merge with Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, merge

When performing a merge with Mercurial, it wants to merge conflicting files one at a time which just isn't a productive workflow on large merge sets.  Instead, what I would like to do is merge the entire changesets of both heads (like using kdiff3 to diff 2 heads).  To me that sounds straightforward but I can't figure out how to achieve it.

So far, the closest I can get is to go through the merge the usual way, leave all the conflicts unresolved (a file at a time...), and then `hg vdiff  -rHead1 -rHead2` - but vdiff (using kdiff3) doesn't seem to have options for passing the tool an output dir (the current working dir) and instead launches with the output dir as a tempdir (possibly -o is the answer?).

Let me put it another way - I want to use kdiff to merge two heads into my working directory.  I want the results in my working dir to be my merge that I can commit.

I must be missing something obvious, I can't be the only one who wants to do this.

Comment: I was a little confused by the phrasing of the question.  Changesets in Mercurial are immutable pieces of history; here IIUC you want to merge a whole tree of files at once instead of file-by-file.

Answer (score 4):

I came up with a solution that achieves what I want but I still feel like it's a kludge.

- Start with an empty working dir with 2 heads: Mine and Theirs.
- Update working dir to Mine: 

  `hg update [My head's rev here]`
- Perform a merge, but fail all files that Merc can't handle automatically without launching a merge tool and keep "My" files when in conflict: 

  `hg --config "ui.merge=internal:fail" merge`

See https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks#head-9f405488b6d3b3d092a09aafa28db515ba44c742 for how-to merge/fail details.

Now I've got a working dir with as much as auto could figure out, but any outstanding files still untouched from Mine.  (Use hg resolve -l to see the Mercurial's resolution status of current files)

- Now I can vdiff my working dir against the Theirs head which gives me the high level, changeset-to-changeset merge that I was looking for.

`hg vdiff -r [Theirs head's rev here]`

Note: If you're using WinMerge for your vdiffs , then make sure it has an /r switch as an option which will do a subdirectory compare and - if WinMerge config is set to use Tree-View - will give a great tree comparison.  From Mercurial.ini:

`[extdiff]

cmd.vdiff = C:\Program Files\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe

opts.vdiff = /e /ub /r /dl other /dr local`


Now I can work the entire directory which includes the unresolved files and make project wide changes as necessary (ie. maybe resolving one file requires additional changes in another).

- When done use resolve to mark all files resolved for Merc and then commit. 

  `hg resolve  -m`

Whew!  Here's hoping this helps someone else!

Comment: Seems like a perfect though indeed kludgy solution :) You should accept it as your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

I relayed the question to `#mercurial` on irc.freenode.net a couple of days ago. `mpm` (the author of Mercurial) gave sort of an answer (it was only half an answer, so I didn't immediately pass it on here). He said that one might be able to do something where you let Mercurial merge the files automatically (and insert the `<<<<` and `>>>>` merge markers where there are conflicts).

Then use a merge tool that knows about these markers: this will let you resolve them all at once instead of doing it on a file by file basis. A starting point would be the page on [merge tool configuration](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/MergeToolConfiguration). It explains that

```
[ui]
merge = internal:merge
```

will make Mercurial inserte the merge markers. Here I tested it by making two files `x.txt` and `y.txt` which I then modified with conflicting changes in two clones. The merge simply gave:

```
% hg merge
merging x.txt
warning: conflicts during merge.
merging x.txt failed!
merging y.txt
warning: conflicts during merge.
merging y.txt failed!
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 2 files unresolved
use 'hg resolve' to retry unresolved file merges or 'hg up --clean' to abandon
```

All files were processed in one go, I did not have to confirm anything per file like you describe.

The files now contain merge markers like this:

```
% cat x.txt
foo
<<<<<<< local
hehe
=======
foobar
>>>>>>> other
```

The next step is to find a tool that can take a directory tree with such files and let you resolve them. I looked at kdiff3, but did not figure out how to use it to operate on a single file alone, it seems very focused on comparing pairs of files/directories.

I'm not sure how much this half answer helps you -- maybe you also got stuck at this point? But I hope it can help others who want to have the merge markers inserted into all files and then resolve the conflicts by hand.

Comment: You were close on the notion of letting the unresolved files stick around.  I think I came up with a more complete answer, but using this strategy, that I just posted here.

Comment: I'm very glad you at least found a way to achieve it, even though it isn't a perfect way. One could make an extension to make the work flow better, but I do so few merges myself that I won't be writing it :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](http://kevin-berridge.blogspot.com/2009/04/what-mercurial-cant-do-merge-by.html) answers your question.

Comment: Good article, but I'm still only looking to merge heads (not changesets in mid branch).  My question wasn't entirely clear on this point.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting ui.merge.  See [this page](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MergeProgram) for more details.

Comment: maybe my question isn't clear enough - regardless of the ui.merge setting, I'll still get a file-at-a-time merge from mercurial, rather than an entire changeset vs. changeset merge (unless I'm missing something?)

Comment: I'm still a little confused--wouldn't you still need kdiff to show you conflicting files one at a time? Or can it resolve all your conflicts without manual intervention?

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you want the `extdiff` command:

i have these in my ~/.hgrc (I prefer meld, but you can change it to kdiff3, etc)

```
[extensions]
hgext.extdiff =

[extdiff]
# add new command called meld, runs meld (no need to name twice)
cmd.meld =
```

With `extdiff` your merges occur in your working directory, and moreover you can pass any extra parameters to your diff program with -o:

```
$ hg help extdiff
```

> hg extdiff [OPT]... [FILE]...
>
> use external program to diff
>   repository (or selected files)
>
> ```
> Show differences between revisions for the specified files, using
> an external program.  The default program used is diff, with
> default options "-Npru".
>
> To select a different program, use the -p option.  The program
> will be passed the names of two directories to compare.  To pass
> additional options to the program, use the -o option.  These will
> be passed before the names of the directories to compare.
>
> When two revision arguments are given, then changes are
> shown between those revisions. If only one revision is
> specified then that revision is compared to the working
> directory, and, when no revisions are specified, the
> working directory files are compared to its parent.
> ```
>
> options:
>
> -p --program  comparison program to run
>    -o --option   pass option to comparison program
>    -r --rev      revision
>    -I --include  include names matching the given patterns
>    -X --exclude  exclude names matching the given patterns

Comment: My problem is that is still file by file, and doesn't give me an entire changeset vs. changeset merge approach.